# Linear system inspection

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Let $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}$. Solve the following system:

$2\lambda x+5y-15z = -5\mu$

$2x+2\lambda y+9z = 4\mu$

$2x+3y+\lambda z = \mu$

for $\lambda ,\mu \in \mathbb{R}$

What I did was calculate the determinants:

$D=4\lambda(\lambda-1)(\lambda+1)$

$D_x=-10\mu\lambda(\lambda-1)$

$D_y=8\mu\lambda(\lambda-1)$

$D_z=4\mu\lambda(\lambda-1)$

and notice that for $\lambda\neq 0,\pm1$ and $\mu\in \mathbb{R}$ we have

$x=\frac{D_x}{D}=\frac{-5\mu}{2(\lambda+1)}$

$y=\frac{D_y}{D}=\frac{2\mu}{\lambda+1}$

$z=\frac{D_z}{D}=\frac{\mu}{\lambda+1}$

So now I will just check each of the cases $\lambda=0,\pm 1$ separately.

First we observe that if $\lambda=-1 \Rightarrow \mu=0$, for if $\mu\neq0$ it follows $D=0$ but $D_x\neq0, D_y\neq0, D_z\neq0$ so the system has no solutions. So we substitute these values and we have a family of infinite solutions.

Next I tried $\lambda=0$ and the system became:

$5y-15z = -5\mu$

$2x+9z = 4\mu$

$2x+3y = \mu$

Here I noticed that the first equation is a linear combination of the second and the third one so the system is equivalent to:

$2x+9z = 4\mu$

$2x+3y = \mu$

which yields another family of solutions for arbitrary $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$

Finally we check the case $\lambda=1$ and then we are done.

My question is, how do I efficiently (I tried the Gaussian reduction algorithm but it takes a lot of steps and many different cases when dividing with the parameters) solve these systems in general? Is there a faster way than the brute-force approach demonstrated here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to find the nullspace of
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2\lambda & 5 & -15 & 5\\
2 & 2\lambda & 9 & -4\\
2 & 3 & \lambda  &-1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
via Gauss. Actually it is the span of
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{5}{2(\lambda+1)}\\
\frac{2}{\lambda+1}\\
\frac{1}{\lambda+1}\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
if $\lambda\neq-1$, otherwise it's the span of
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{5}{2}\\
2\\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$